# How can Xcode successfully access data the program cannot?

Tags: swift, generics, exc-bad-access

I'm running Xcode 9, Swift 4, High Sierra. In my code I have a mapping that, cut out and stripped down, includes this as the first lines in the closure:

```
let foo = graph.edges.map { (edge: Edge<Node>) -> (Int, Int) in
    print(edge)
    let fromvertex = (edge.from as? VertexElement)
        .
        .
        .
}
```

There's a breakpoint on the line `let from vertex ...`

When run, the code is successful up to the breakpoint, which is where the problem starts. If at that point I execute `po edge.from` in the debugger, I get the expected result. If I step one line, and so execute the assignment, I get `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=*whatever*)`. I can then execute `po edge.from` or even `po (edge.from as? VertexElement)` at that point and still get the expected results.

How can this be? There's no optional involved in `edge.from`, and I'd think the data is there correctly since the debugger finds it.

Edge is (as you'd expect) a generic class, with the first part of the definition being this:

```
public class Edge<T>: NSObject, NSCoding, Codable where T: Hashable {
    public typealias Weight = SimWeight

    public let from: Vertex<T>
    public let to: Vertex<T>
    public var weight: Weight? = nil
        .
        .
        .
}
```

and then, the first part of Vertex, also a generic, looks like this:

```
public struct Vertex<T>: Equatable, Codable where T: Hashable {
    public var data: T
    public let index: Int
    public var gridX: Int?
    public var gridY: Int?
        .
        .
        .
}
```

Node is another, concrete class (not a generic)

Finally, I have address sanitization turned on.

All that said, I neither can see where the exception is coming from, nor why the debugger can get the data when the program cannot. Any ideas what's wrong (or even how to debug it?)

Comment: Set up an exception breakpoint in debugger, that should show you the exact error message. `There's no optional involved in edge.from` that's not true, since you are optional casting the value, hence making it optional. The type of `fromvertex` becomes `VertexElement?` due to the optional casting. You need to (safely) unwrap that value to make it non-optional, but keep in mind that the error might not have to do anything with optionals, without seeing the exact error message it's quite hard to tell.

Comment: I keep Swift error, All exceptions, and Constraint error enabled as user-level breakpoints. The exception without question is on the line I've identified -  it's the top of the traceback, and there's nothing else reported. I'd been hoping for that to help, but no.

Comment: What is `VertexElement` here? A protocol, I assume? Also, what happens if you `po edge.from as? VertexElement` in the debugger?

Comment: It's simply a type alias for Vertex<Node>. I missed that cleaning up the code for explanation. The direct answer to your question is that it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only suspect a compiler problem, because it's fixed now by reorganizing the code. Specifically, I created this method within Edge:

```
func indirectEdge() throws -> IndirectEdge {
    guard let fromvx = self.from as? VertexElement,
        let tovx = self.to as? VertexElement,
        let weight = self.weight else {throw TypeError.notVertex}
    return IndirectEdge(from: fromvx.index, to: tovx.index, weight: weight)
}
```

and then changed the code at the top of this post to be:

```
guard let indirectEdges = try? graph.edges.map({ (edge) throws -> IndirectEdge in
    return try edge.indirectEdge()
}) else {throw SimFileError.unimplementedOperation(why: "Don't know how to encode this graph")}
    .
    .
    .
```

At that point everything began to work, without the exceptions. (yes, I changed the later code to accept the IndirectEdge; that code is further on and shouldn't have any effect.) What I *expected* was that the exception would move into the indirectEdge method, but that's not what happened. It's good the code works now, but scary that I can't figure out why.